# Creating variable in function and working with the reference

Tags: c++

Is it "good practice" to create a variable inside a function and giving a reference back?

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

int* add(int* a, int* b)
{
  int c = *a + *b; // c is created here and a reference is given back
  int* p_c;
  p_c = &c;
}

main()
{
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;

  int* p_c = add(&a, &b);

  std::cout << *p_c << std::endl;
}
```

In the main function *p_c gives me the correct value. However, the value is created in the fuction add. Is this causing problems?

Comment: `Is it "good practice" to create a variable inside a function and giving a reference back?` - **NO**

Comment: You should always compile with warnings enabled `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, they will tell you what is wrong with your code.

Comment: It's not just not a good practice, it will cause undefined behavior. Usually pretty quickly too.

Comment: I don't see any return value. UB in 2 cases in a single function :-)

Comment: @Scheff That's not fatal. Not returning a value is.

Comment: Those aren't even references. They're pointers. And your function that is supposed to return a `int*` isn't returning anything.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Oops. Overlooked.

Comment: It is natural to wonder about such a thing. Nearly every C or C++ programmer has made this error at least once. The question is not a bad one in of itself. The minimal example has errors is probably the primary detractor besides it being a fairly common duplicate.

Comment: All functions in C++ must have a declared return type (may be `void`) and the one of `main` must be `int`. Yours is missing one. Add to the compiler flags mentioned above for warnings also the flag `-pedantic-errors` which will tell your more clearly if you don't follow standard C++ rules.

Comment: your code looks like you think using more pointers would make code better. That isnt the case. If possible references are to be preferred, but you do not even need a reference to add two numbers in a function and return the result.